slate is throw an error in the built Next project
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Object.compare (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:369316)
    at Object.compare (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:387860)
    at Object.isAfter (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:387964)
    at Object.isBackward (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:376178)
    at Object.edges (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:375145)
    at 588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:457775
    at Object.string (588-208df54dccab14d1.js:1:457963)

it works properly when launched locally.
